# minimizing webapge changes alignment and nav bar

Tags: html, css

```css
/*MULTI PAGE*/

.navhead{
 
    width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #333;  
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    position: absolute;
        
}
.navid {
 
    width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #fffaf0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #333;
     top: 89;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.navid ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    list-style: none;
   display:inline-block;text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    margin-left: 725;
}

.navid li:first-of-type a {
 border-left: 1px solid #333; }
.navid li a:hover {
 color: #fffaf0;
 background-color: #ffdd99; }

.navid li {
 float: left; }
.navid li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 border-right: 1px solid #333; }

body {
    
    min-width: 720px;
    background-color: #ffdd99;
    font-family: monospace;
}


.container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto; /* Auto adjust margin */
margin-top: 150
}

h1 { color: #fffaf0; 
text-align: center; 
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 35;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}
    
    /*HOME PAGE*/
 
.images{
     
    display: block;
    margin-left: 647;
    margin-top: 50;
}

.images1{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 545;
    margin-top: 25;
}

.images2{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 647;
    margin-top: 25;
}


.images3{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 545;
    margin-top: 25;
}

.drop {
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
   
   
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 1px solid #333;
    
}


.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="contain">
<head>

<div class="navhead"><h1>Meadow Manor</h1> </div>   
</head>

<nav>
<div class="navid">
<ul>
<li> <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li>    <a class="active" href="about.html">About</a> </li>
<li>  <a class="active" class="active" href="local.html">Nearby</a></li>  
<li>  <a class="active" href="owner.html">Directions</a> </li>
<li>    <a class="active" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> </li>

</ul>

</div>    
</nav>
</div>
<body>

<div class="images">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="livingroom3.jpg" alt="living room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="livingroom3.jpg" alt="living room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Living room with patio doors</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="house.jpg" alt="house" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="house.jpg" alt="house" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Street view of the property</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="livingroom1.jpg" alt="living room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="livingroom1.jpg" alt="living room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Living room with fireplace</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>      

<div class="images1">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="Kitchen.jpg" alt="kitchen" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="Kitchen.jpg" alt="kitchen" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Kitchen area</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="sink.jpg" alt="sink" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="sink.jpg" alt="sink" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Washing-up sink</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="diningroom1.jpg" alt="dining room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="diningroom1.jpg" alt="dining room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Dining area with door view</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="drop">
<img src="diningroom2.jpg" alt="dining room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="diningroom2.jpg" alt="dining room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Dining area with window view</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="images2">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="bedroom1.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bedroom1.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Queen-size double bedroom</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="bedroom2.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bedroom2.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Wardrobe and desk space</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="bathroom1.jpg" alt="bathroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bathroom1.jpg" alt="bathroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Ensuite bathroom</div>
</div>
</div>


 </div>

 <div class="images3">      

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="bedroom3.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="bedroom3.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">King-size double bedroom</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="shower.jpg" alt="shower" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="shower.jpg" alt="shower" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">Ensuite shower</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">Large storage space</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="garden1.jpg" alt="garden" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="garden1.jpg" alt="garden" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">The garden area</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>    


</body>        

<footer> </footer>
</div>
</html>
```

minimising the web browser causing nav. bar to mess up, if you open the webpage up in browser and then minimise the screen you will be able to see the change in the nav. bar.
Thanks for the help!
My homepage.css file

```
.navhead{

width: 100%;
padding: 0;
background-color: #333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #333;  
margin-top: 0px;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
position: absolute

}
.navid {

width: 100%;
padding: 0;
background-color: #fffaf0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
float: left; 
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #333;
top: 89;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
}
.navid ul {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 800px;
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
margin-left: 725;
}

.navid li:first-of-type a {
 border-left: 1px solid #333; }

.navid li a:hover {
 color: #fffaf0;
 background-color: #ffdd99; }

.navid li {
float: left; }
.navid li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: underline;
font-weight: bold;
color: #333;
border-right: 1px solid #333; }

body {

min-width: 1200px;
background-color: #ffdd99;
font-family: monospace;
}


.container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto; /* Auto adjust margin */
margin-top: 150
}
```

My index.html file

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
<div class="container">
<head>
<div class="navhead"><h1>Meadow Manor</h1> </div>   
</head>

<nav>
<div class="navid">
<ul>
<li> <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li>    <a class="active" href="about.html">About</a> </li>
<li>  <a class="active" class="active" href="local.html">Nearby</a></li>  
<li>  <a class="active" href="owner.html">Directions</a> </li>
<li>    <a class="active" href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> </li>

</ul>

</div>    
</nav>

<body>

<div class="images">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="livingroom3.jpg" alt="living room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="livingroom3.jpg" alt="living room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Living room with patio doors</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="house.jpg" alt="house" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="house.jpg" alt="house" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Street view of the property</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="livingroom1.jpg" alt="living room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="livingroom1.jpg" alt="living room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Living room with fireplace</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>      

<div class="images1">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="Kitchen.jpg" alt="kitchen" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="Kitchen.jpg" alt="kitchen" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Kitchen area</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="sink.jpg" alt="sink" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="sink.jpg" alt="sink" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Washing-up sink</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="diningroom1.jpg" alt="dining room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="diningroom1.jpg" alt="dining room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Dining area with door view</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="drop">
<img src="diningroom2.jpg" alt="dining room" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="diningroom2.jpg" alt="dining room" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Dining area with window view</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="images2">      

<div class="drop">
<img src="bedroom1.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bedroom1.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Queen-size double bedroom</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="bedroom2.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bedroom2.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Wardrobe and desk space</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="drop">
<img src="bathroom1.jpg" alt="bathroom" width="200" height="150">
<div class="drop-content">
<img src="bathroom1.jpg" alt="bathroom" width="400" height="300">
<div class="desc">Ensuite bathroom</div>
</div>
</div>


 </div>

 <div class="images3">      

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="bedroom3.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="bedroom3.jpg" alt="bedroom" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">King-size double bedroom</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="shower.jpg" alt="shower" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="shower.jpg" alt="shower" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">Ensuite shower</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">Large storage space</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="drop">
 <img src="garden1.jpg" alt="garden" width="200" height="150">
 <div class="drop-content">
 <img src="garden1.jpg" alt="garden" width="400" height="300">
 <div class="desc">The garden area</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>    


</body>        

<footer> </footer>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Either create a working code-example using the code-snippet function here, or at least link to the page in question, since pasting just the code doesn't really do much without us having to set up a test-page.

Comment: how do I create code snippet-example

Comment: Do you see the buttons above the form when you chose to either edit, submit a question, or answer? If you hover over them, you'll find it. It's the button right of the tiny image-button.

Comment: You have HTML tags where there shouldn't be. All page markup should be contained within `<body>`. You have markup in the `<head>` and outside of `<head>` and `<body>`. Fix those first. Then learn what block and inline elements are. I see you're setting `.container` to `100%` width and its margin when you don't need to.

Comment: I have added snippet; however, it does not show what the webpage looks like when in browser properly and the change when minimised